# Using a vector as an array index?

Tags: opencl

Under OpenCL, is there a method for accessing an array using a vector as an index?

For example, I want to accomplish something like this:

```
__constant uint data[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77};

uchar4 keys = (uchar4)(5, 0, 2, 6);
uint4 results = data[keys]; 
// results = (uint4)(0x55, 0x00, 0x22, 0x66);
```

More generically:

```
// Array of scalar type T
T data[] = {value_0, value_1, ...};

// n-item vector of type V
Vn keys = (Vn)(index_0, index_1, ...); 

// n-item vector of type T
Tn result = data[keys];
```

---

Currently, the only way I can accomplish something like this is to do it manually, but it doesn't feel very "vector-y":

```
__constant uint data[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77};

uchar4 keys = (uchar4)(5, 0, 2, 6);
uint4 results = (uint4)(data[keys.s0], data[keys.s1], data[keys.s2], data[keys.s3]);
// results = (uint4)(0x55, 0x00, 0x22, 0x66);
```

So I guess this is a two part question:

1. Is there a way to access an array using a vector as an index?
2. If not, is there a more efficient way than I've showcased above?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL C is based on C99 standard, which doesn't allow array index to be vector.
Last sample of your code is pretty much what you can get. Also, take into account that using vector elements as array index leads to poor memory access pattern, which can decrease IO performance dramatically.